# Monitoring Java EE Application

Tags: java, glassfish, visualvm, payara

I am deploying several applications over Payara Server. With VisualVM I can see the CPU, RAM etc. usage of the Glassfish Server. My problem is that I need to see the usage of each deployed application on the server seperatet.

Does anybody has an idea how I could monitor this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be quite difficult since application servers are designed to share at least basic components/classes between applications.

However, you could try to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html to find the CPU usage of all threads and filter those out that are not interesting to you (maybe by package name).